# general advise regarding user management in application

Tags: database

I want a general advise from database programmers. While developing an application, is it advisable to complete the user management section for user rights etc and then the main application is to be developed? what i practice is that i first develop application. and then go to user management section. please advise what is the professional and correct way of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question refers to  the concept of authentication and authorization in your app, then I recommend having at least a concept beforehand. I saw systems where user management was ignored or implemented overly simple at first, without a clear concept in mind. These systems then have a hard time realizing a clean and secure authorization and authentication.

The effort you will need for user management increases quickly with a growing app.

Comment: Basically my question is about giving different roles to different users. i.e questions like If Admin logs in he / she whould have access to which components / pages. If Boss logs in he / she would only see reports...if data entry operator logs in he /she would see only the data entry pages etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You can also call this authentication (identifying who someone is by login or otherwise) and authorization (granting access to that person to different parts of the app, as you describe). As in my answer, I strongly recommend integrating it early in your app.

Answer (score 0):

These two things can be handled separately. So if you have chosen to develop your app first and then add the user management part, nothing bad will occur.